# combining multiple sentences into one

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, summary

Given following sentences, for example:

```
A cat is on a bed.
The color of the cat is brown.
The bed is small.
```

Is there a way to combine/summarize the sentences into a single sentence such as:

```
A brown cat is on a small bed.
```

I have no knowledge of summary extraction/generation, but can it hopefully be exploited for this purpose?

Comment: Sounds pretty hard. Typical text summarisation doesn't merge sentences, but only ranks them by importance. Or are you trying to do this only for sentences of the form "X is Y"? Real-world text is way more complex than this toy example...

Comment: Text summarization with TensorFlow - https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/text-summarization-with-tensorflow.html

Comment: @lenz It's pretty much going to be of the form "X is Y". Would it be feasible in that case?

Comment: If it's kind of artificial data, you can try with POS tagging and some transformation rules. But you should have a look at the TensorFlow link provided by RAVI, it looks pretty fancy.

Comment: This is the thing I want to, but it may be very difficult to determine what is the issue of input sentences and represent it as a phrase. It seems Tensorflow's summarizing (or similar seq2seq summarizing) is only removing unnecessary adverbs or such that, and it can be only applied for one sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a project called DLTR (Do Little Things Right) whose demo can be found here: https://nlp.1theta.com/

There's a section called `BridgeBlend` and I'm wondering if this is what you're looking for?

```
BridgeBlend Demo

Input Statement-1
John loves eating pizza.

Input Statement-2
pizza is a food made using cheese.

Output:
John loves eating pizza, a food made using cheese.
```

As for your example:

```
Input Statement-1
The color of the cat is brown.

Input Statement-2
The cat is on a bed.

Input Statement-3
The bed is small.

Output:
The cat is on a small bed and its color is brown.
```

Comment: Hi, tried accesing to https://nlp.1theta.com/ to try BridgeBlend, but seems that the server is down, do you have a repo or something like that were I could chek it?